# Adjustable Voltage Regulator Resistor Values

Tags: resistors, voltage-regulator

I'm working with an adjustable voltage regulator and am having a hard time understanding my equation for determining resistor values.

Datasheet: http://www.chinaeds.com/zl/20103612559506780_AS2850YU-X,AS2850YT-X,AS2850AUPDF.pdf

[image: Figure 2]

I'm able to get ~5V (my goal) on `Vout` when using the following values:

- `Vin` = 12V
- `R1` = 22K
- `R2` = 1.47K (1K and 470 in series)

As soon as I put a load on `Vout` it drops to ~3.7V

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: turns out I had multiple regulators that were bad. Once I found a good one everything works as expected (with the proper resistance values).

Comment: The input voltage has to be more than 6.2V at the troughs of any ripple to get a solid 5V out (preferably somewhat more than that). It is probably dropping under the load.

Comment: My power supply (12V 1A) works perfectly fine with a fixed output voltage regulator. (http://datasheet.octopart.com/L7805CV-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-7264666.pdf) TO-220 package. I just need a tiny bit more than the 1.5A it can handle.

Comment: You're pulling 1.5A out of the this regulator _and_ your 1A power supply? Hmmmm ... do you have a heat sink on your regulator? have you checked you 12V in at 1.5A?

Comment: @MichaelAmbrose: so you are pulling more than 1.5A through a regulator rated for 1.5A from a PSU rated at 1A?

Comment: Heatsink: yes. More than 1.5: trying to run a Raspberry Pi so only at peaks. That's why I got a different regulator. The final install will be using a 12V 3A adapter. The fact that I can get 5V from the fixed regulator makes me think I'm doing something wrong with my calculation. ** To clarify**: everything works perfectly fine with the 12V 1A PSU and 1.5A regulator. I just can't use it as my final install.

Comment: The equation given in the datasheet (which seems consistent) does not give a resulting output of 5V with the resistor values you chose (assuming a Vref of 1.25V). Are you sure you wired this correctly ?

Comment: Double checked the wiring and everything looks correct. I should say- I don't know how to calculate the Vref and couldn't really get the equation to work. The values I found were from trial and error.

Comment: a VERY MAJOR POINT TO NOTE IS THAT THE REGULATOR OPERATES FROM THE VOLTAGE DIFFERNTIAL Vin-vout and the output load MUST be able to sink the regulators operating current. The current can be sunk by the divider nd/or the load. If no load is provided then the divider MUST sing this current.
The data sheet says Ireg is 10 mA. For 1.2V across R1 the maximum value opf R1 = R = V/I = 1.2/.010 = 120 Ohms. R1 is vastly too high and non-failure is not an option :-) :-(.
So ...

Comment: ... 
Look at Fig 6 and Fig 7 in data sheet and note value of R1. If you use 120 Ohm in this location the divider design will work as per spec sheet. OR load output with R <= V/I = 5V/0.010A = 500 Ohms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The current \$I_{ADJ}\$ is very small and
>   constant. Therefore its contribution to the overall output
>   voltage is very small and can generally be ignored.

\$I_{ADJ}\$ is 40-80\$\mu\$A.

So how are you getting 5V? Calc gives:

\$ V_{OUT} = V_{REF} \times \left({1 + \frac {R_2} {R_1}} \right) = 1.25V \times \left({1 + \frac {1.47k\Omega} {22k\Omega}} \right) =  1.333V \$

I'd replace \$R_1\$ with 120\$\Omega\$.  Standard value from LM337 calcs.

\$ R_{2} = \left( {\frac {V_{OUT}} {V_{REF}} - 1} \right) \times {R_1}  = \left( {\frac {5V} {1.25V} - 1} \right) \times {120\Omega} = 360\Omega\$

Comment: I'm wondering if there's something wrong with this regulator. Using 100Ω and 300Ω or 120Ω and 360Ω I get 1V and 1.6V respectively.

Comment: The regulator is crap.  If you ground the ADJ you should get reference voltage as output.  But \$ R_2 \$ must be greater than \$ R_1 \$.

Comment: Should that be on `Vout`?

Comment: Yes.  The reference is a 1.25V zener.

Comment: With 12V on `Vin` and grounding ADJ I get ~10.9V on `Vout`

Comment: Bingo! Your values work perfectly. I had already tried multiple regulators and was getting the same result. One of them works perfectly. Either I was unlucky and got 2 bad ones or these are really low quality and die easily.

Comment: It has thermal and overload protection.  I'd suspect the supplier.  The one advantage of linear supplies is that they are virtually indestructible.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't 100% clear from the datasheet, but based on the language below figure 2, it looks like this regulator requires a ~10mA reference current through R1 to maintain regulation. If this is true, then you should put a 500 ohm resistor in place of R1, and recalculate your other values.

Comment: hmm.. Tried this but I still experience the voltage drop.

Answer (score 1):

This part is a linear LDO regulator. You **cannot** get more current out of it than you put into it, so your 12V 1A supply can provide only 5V at 1A (plus a lot of heat, and minus a few mA the regulator itself uses).

If you really need 1.5A at 5V you should use a switching regulator, in which case your 12W power supply will work fine, and the regulator should run cool. This regulator will not. Even if your 12V supply could deliver 1.5A it would be dissipating more than 10W which means a big heatsink and/or a fan.

Edit: If you are seeing the drop with a light load, you are probably experiencing oscillation. The output capacitor on virtually all LDO regulators is *not* optional (they really **should** show it in all the schematics on the datasheet). It should be 100uF electrolytic or 22uF tantalum in this case. Without the cap you will definitely see oscillation at the output for some load resistances and this could account for a multimeter reading of 3.7V

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Why do I still have a voltage drop even with minimal load? Even if I add an LED to `Vout` I still experience the voltage drop.

Comment: @MichaelAmbrose See my edit.

Comment: All I have laying around right now is a 10uF electrolytic and a few ceramics. I'll have to pick up a few more components before I can figure out what's really going on here. Thanks for the input!